# pandas get unique values from column of lists

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, unique

How do I get the unique values of a column of lists in pandas or numpy such that second column from

[image]

would result in `'action', 'crime', 'drama'`.

The closest (but non-functional) solutions I could come up with were:

```
 genres = data['Genre'].unique()
```

But this predictably results in a TypeError saying how lists aren't hashable.

`TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`

Set seemed to be a good idea but

`genres = data.apply(set(), columns=['Genre'], axis=1)`

but also results in a
`TypeError: set() takes no keyword arguments`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you only want to find the unique values, I'd recommend using `itertools.chain.from_iterable` to concatenate all those lists

```
import itertools

>>> np.unique([*itertools.chain.from_iterable(df.Genre)])
array(['action', 'crime', 'drama'], dtype='<U6')
```

Or even faster

```
>>> set(itertools.chain.from_iterable(df.Genre))
{'action', 'crime', 'drama'}
```

---

### `Timings`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Genre':[['crime','drama'],['action','crime','drama']]})
df = pd.concat([df]*10000)

%timeit set(itertools.chain.from_iterable(df.Genre))
100 loops, best of 3: 2.55 ms per loo
    
%timeit set([x for y in df['Genre'] for x in y])
100 loops, best of 3: 4.09 ms per loop

%timeit np.unique([*itertools.chain.from_iterable(df.Genre)])
100 loops, best of 3: 12.8 ms per loop

%timeit np.unique(df['Genre'].sum())
1 loop, best of 3: 1.65 s per loop

%timeit set(df['Genre'].sum())
1 loop, best of 3: 1.66 s per loop
```

Answer (score 35):

You can use `explode`:

```py
data = pd.DataFrame([
    {
        "title": "The Godfather: Part II",
        "genres": ["crime", "drama"],
        "director": "Fracis Ford Coppola"
    },
    {
        "title": "The Dark Knight",
        "genres": ["action", "crime", "drama"],
        "director": "Christopher Nolan"
    }
])
# Changed from data.explode("genres")["genres"].unique() as suggested by rafaelc
data["genres"].explode().unique()
```

Results in:

```
array(['crime', 'drama', 'action'], dtype=object)
```

Comment: @rafaelc Yep! And also much faster. :P (though not nearly as fast as `itertools`)

Comment: This is good ... but what if you need keep the lists as a whole, this would not work ...

Comment: @LucasAimaretto That was not part of the question, and would be a strange requirement either way.

Comment: This is the best solution IMO

Answer (score 2):

Here are some options:

```
# toy data
df = pd.DataFrame({'Genre':[['crime','drama'],['action','crime','drama']]})

np.unique(df['Genre'].sum())
# 109 µs ± 2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

set(df['Genre'].sum())
# 87 µs ± 1.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

set([x  for y in df['Genre'] for x in y])
# 11.8 µs ± 126 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're just looking to extract the information and not add back to the DataFrame, you can utilize Python's set method in a for loop:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'movie':[[1,2,3],[1,2,6]]})
out = set()
for row in df['movie']:
    out.update({item for item in row})
print(out)
```

You could also wrap this in an apply call if you wanted (which would return None but update the set in place):

```
out = set()
df['movie'].apply(lambda x: out.update({item for item in x}))
```

Personally I think the for loop is a bit clearer to read.

Answer (score 1):

Use the power of [**sets**](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#set) for **chained uniqueness**.
I've used this technique with huge lists, in big data like envs'. The main pro here is cut down the time needed to produce a final flat list.

1. Convert the list-column into sets
2. Reduce all sets into a final set, using [union](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.union)

Try:

```
from functools import reduce # for python 3

l = df.Genre.dropna().tolist()
sets = [ set(i) for i in l ]
final_set = reduce(lambda x, y: x.union(y), sets)
```

- In big-data like envs', like spark, use map to convert each list into a set, then reduce like the above.
- Change union to [**intersection**](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.intersection), if you need to get all **common** values from all lists.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's exactly what you wanted, but this will allow you to convert it into a set.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Movie':['The Godfather', 'Dark Knight'], 'Genre': [['Crime', 'Drama'],['Crime', 'Drama', 'Action']]})

genres = []
for sublist in df['Genre']:
    for item in sublist:
        genres.append(item)

genre_set = set(genres)

print(genre_set)
```

Output: {'Action', 'Drama', 'Crime'}