# How to get unique lists in a Pandas column of lists

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ["John", "Jack", "Jeff", "Kate"], "hobbies":[["pirates"], ["pirates"], ["climbing", "yoga"], ["yoga"]]})

# name  hobbies
# 0 John    [pirates]
# 1 Jack    [pirates]
# 2 Jeff    [climbing, yoga]
# 3 Kate    [yoga]
```

I would like to have a list of the unique lists in hobbies.
Just to be clear, I don't want the list of unique hobbies (i.e. `["pirates", "climbing", "yoga"]`), which is already covered in several questions including this one: [pandas get unique values from column of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58528989/pandas-get-unique-values-from-column-of-lists)

I would like instead the list `[['pirates'], ['yoga'], ['climbing', 'yoga']]`.

I have thought of the following way but that does not seem very "panda-ic":

```
[list(t) for t in {tuple(h) for h in df["hobbies"]}]
```

Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `numpy` to do it:

```
import numpy as np

np.unique(df['hobbies'].to_numpy()).tolist()
```

Comment: Nice that should be faster i think! +1

Comment: The simplest solution. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Let us change the `list` to `tuple` so we can do `drop_duplicates`

```
out = df.hobbies.apply(tuple).drop_duplicates().apply(list).tolist()
Out[143]: [['pirates'], ['climbing', 'yoga'], ['yoga']]
```

If you do not need converting back to `list`, you could do:

```
df.hobbies.apply(tuple).unique()
```

Comment: I actually had the second solution but found it ugly as tuples. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

lists aren't hashable keys, use a tuple instead and then convert to list

```
[*map(list,df['hobbies'].map(tuple).unique())]
```

---

output:

```
[['pirates'], ['climbing', 'yoga'], ['yoga']]
```

---

the use of unpacking over calling a list on a map object has proven faster for me

```
%%timeit
list(map(list,df['hobbies'].map(tuple).unique()))
385 µs ± 67.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
%%timeit
[*map(list,df['hobbies'].map(tuple).unique())]
296 µs ± 15.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: Why the complex `[* ... ]`? Would not that be simpler to put `list(map(list,df['hobbies'].map(tuple).unique()))` ?

Comment: @Jean-FrancoisT. you are correct. edited my answer why I use it. havent extensively tested it though

Comment: Interesting comparison. You learn every day :)